# In Kusto (KQL), how can I restrict results to one row based on a unique pairing of two other columns?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

| car | owner |
| --- | --- |
| Car | James |
| Bike | James |
| Bus | James |
| Bus | James |
| Car | Betty |
| Bike | Betty |
| Bike | Betty |
| Car | Mike |
| Car | Mike |

I want the data to look like this:

| Owner | Vehicles |
| --- | --- |
| James | 3 |
| Betty | 2 |
| Mike | 1 |

What I need is to list out, by owner, how many total vehicles they have. Due to the way the data is stored, there are multiple entries in this table (due to updates to information on other columns not shown).

If this were SQL, I'd do something like this:

```sql
SELECT owner, SELECT count(*) from vehicles where vehicles.owner = car_records.owner) as Vehicles 
FROM car_records
```

I've tried a variety of combinations of let=query and joins and distincts and summarizes, but I can't figure out the right combination to get to the goal. If I could reduce the table to only one row per owner+vehicle type, then I'd be fine, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [`dcount()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dcount-aggfunction).

for example:

```
datatable(car:string, owner:string)
[
    'Car', 'James', 
    'Bike', 'James', 
    'Bus', 'James', 
    'Bus', 'James', 
    'Car', 'Betty', 
    'Bike', 'Betty', 
    'Bike', 'Betty', 
    'Car', 'Mike', 
    'Car', 'Mike'
]
| summarize dcount(car) by owner
```

| owner | dcount_car |
| --- | --- |
| James | 3 |
| Betty | 2 |
| Mike | 1 |

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Technically there were still duplicates because of how my tables are set up, but I was able to work that out using join innerunique.